# recursive triangle java program: I keep getting “Exception in thread ”main“

Tags: java, exception, methods

I'm trying to put together a triangle program using methods that will bring results like this with a user input of 4 lines with a character string of "[]" but I keep getting the exception in thread main error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
>       at RecursiveTriangle.getCharacterInputFromUser(RecursiveTriangle.java:28)
>       at RecursiveTriangle.main(RecursiveTriangle.java:56)

Can someone assist?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RecursiveTriangle{
   //Scanner sc= null;

   //method to take the line number input from the user
   int getLinesInputFromUser(){
       int numLines;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       do{
           System.out.println("Enter the number of lines between 1 to 10");
           sc= new Scanner(System.in);
           numLines=sc.nextInt();
       }while(!(numLines>0 && numLines<=10));


       return numLines;

   }

   //method to take the pattern input from the user
   String getCharacterInputFromUser(){
       String pattern;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       do{
           System.out.println("Enter the pattern");
           pattern=sc.next();
       }while(pattern==null || pattern.length()==0);

       sc.close();
       return pattern;
   }

   //method to print the triangle recursively
   void printTriangle(int numLines, String pattern){
       if(numLines != 0){
           int loopCount=numLines;
           while(loopCount>0) {    // loop for printing the pattern numLines times
               System.out.print(pattern);
               loopCount--;
           }
           System.out.println("");// to take the cursor on next line
           printTriangle(--numLines,pattern);
            }
   }





public static void main (String args []){
   RecursiveTriangle recursiveTriangle=new RecursiveTriangle();
   int numLines=recursiveTriangle.getLinesInputFromUser();
   String pattern=recursiveTriangle.getCharacterInputFromUser();
   recursiveTriangle.printTriangle(numLines, pattern);
}
}
```

Comment: If you need help debugging an exception, it would help immensely if you posted the full text from the exception's stacktrace. For instance, we have no idea at this point *what* exception has been thrown, or *what line* throws it. Please fix.

Comment: Just edited my post.

Comment: Thank you -- now which line throws this exception?

Comment: Line: `RecursiveTriangle.java:28`

Comment: One problem I see: You appear to be opening and closing multiple Scanners -- only open **one** Scanner with System.in, and don't close it until your application is completely done using it. Pass it into methods if need be.

Comment: Got it.  I've been looking over it again and again and figured it was something dumb like that.  I declared the scanner under the public class and removed the declarations in each method.  Seems to be running okay now.  Thanks for the quick response.